# Elasticsearch improve scrolling

Tags: elasticsearch

Im having 3 millions document in elastic index 
I need to get all documents so I use "scrolling" 
because I use scrolling, I need to wait till each scroll return and then get the next scroll 
so I get 10,000 results, then another 10,000 results and so on....
the problem is that it took too much time because I go 300 times to the db to get all documents. 
is there another way to get the documents faster?

I need to get all unique combinations between "myId" and all other fields name (only the name, not the value) as the following example: 
**doc1:**

```
    {
myId: 123,
field1: "x",
field2: "y"
}
```

**doc2:**

```
    {
myId: 123,
field1: "x",
field3: "y"
}
```

**doc3:**

```
{
myId: 556,
field1: "x",
field2: "y"
}
```

**expected result:**

```
[
{
myId:123,
fieldName: field1
},
{
myId:123,
fieldName: field2
},
{
myId:123,
fieldName: field3
},
{
myId:556,
fieldName: field1
},
{
myId:556,
fieldName: field2
}
]
```

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: Why do you need to retrieve all documents at once? What are you doing with them?

Comment: If they are separable via some field (like a timestamp), you could do multiple parallel ranged queries. But your use case, data structure, and infrastructure will determine if that is feasible or not.

Comment: @val , Ive edited my question to include example for my logic. if I cant create elastic query to solve my problem.. I need to get all document to my service and run my logic

Comment: @Benjamin Trent  I have 'time' field, but instead of 'parallel ranged queries' I can do "from, size" and run multiple queries at parallel, I tried this and it is better than scrolling but still not good enough

Comment: @BenjaminTrent  any idea?

Comment: @Val did you see the edited question?

Comment: @larryckey I have no idea what "not good enough" means. I do not know your performance requirements. The two options to be "faster than scroll" is to increase `index.max_result_window` option (will cause increase in memory and CPU) and parallel querys/scrolls. A scroll can have a query in it, so you can trivially run 10-100 scrolls in different threads against the cluster. If the parallel scrolls does not work, then its probably a resource constraint (CPU/Memory/Network) on the cluster or the client.